# How can i enable spring filter for a specific url?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

I migrated a spring MVC application on spring boot 1.4.3 application.
I have kept XML configuration for (spring security).
I rewrote the filters in web.xml in java config, with respecting order.

My Problem: 
in SpringSecurityFilterChain I have 2 specific filters (Filter1, Filter2)

Filter1 for `/**` url and Filter2 for `/ws/**` url.

my issue is: ***both filters are applied for all url*** by FilterRegistrationBean.

how can i specify each filter for an URL ?

Comment: Maybe an issue with the order of execution as Filter1 with /** will be executed first which can be mapped for any URL so your /ws/** filter is not applying. you can use @Order

Comment: @PatelRomil, i had changed the order but i have the some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add multiple FilterRegistration per different url pattern

```
 FilterRegistration myFilter = servletContext.addFilter("myFilter ", MyFilter.class);
 myFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/myservlet/myendpoint/*");
 FilterRegistration myFilter2 = servletContext.addFilter("myFilter2 ", MyFilter2.class);
 myFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/myservlet/myendpoint2/*");
```